# What does tail -f <directory name> do?

Tags: bash, tail

I mistakenly executed the following command in the terminal:

`tail -f /logs/applications/logs*`

I got the following output:

```
tail: file shrunk!
Error 0
```

I am not sure what exactly happened. I have not been keeping track on the number of files in the directory for quiet a while. Could someone please explain what exactly happened, and did I lose any files.

Edit:

I am not sure if it is coincidence or not, but after I executed the code, I counted the number of files in the directory, and it was 10!

First time the number 10 got me paranoid...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am not sure what exactly happened.

What happened was that the file was rotated by an external application.  This is usual.  Utilities like `logrotate` *rotate* log files, i.e. the contents of the existing log file are moved to another file and the existing one is *blanked out* before an application starts writing to it again.

When `tail` determines that the size of the tracked file has reduced, then it prints the message you observed and continues tracking the file.

Quoting from [`tail invocation`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html) section of [GNU coreutils manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/):

> No matter which method you use, if the tracked file is determined to
>   have shrunk, `tail` prints a message saying the file has been truncated
>   and resumes tracking the end of the file from the newly-determined
>   endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

No you did not lose any files as `tail` command only shows the end of the files.

Passing `/logs/applications/logs*` to `tail` is same as passing multiple files/folders (anything that matches `/logs/applications/logs*` pattern). As this pattern can be matches also by directories, in these cases `tail` will fail to work.